# GAS: splice sporadically returning incorrect array size

Tags: google-apps-script

I am using GAS to randomly select enemies for a tabletop game. I have gotten as far as randomly selecting rows from a list, removing the first element of the inner array and feeding it back into the sheet. It works for the most part, but sporadically removes the wrong elements.

I've searched here and other forums, rewrote the splice, changed the array  and stared at it for hours and I think I've reached the point where i can't see the woods for the trees and need some fresh eyes.

```
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------//
function selectRandomElements(fromValueRows, count) {
  var pickedRows = []; // This will hold the selected rows
  for (var i = 0; i < count && fromValueRows.length > 0; i++) {
    var pickedIndex = getRandomInt(0, fromValueRows.length);
    // Pick the element at position pickedIndex, and remove it from fromValueRows.
    var pickedRow = fromValueRows.slice(pickedIndex)[0]; 
    // Add the selected row to our result array
    pickedRows.push(pickedRow);
  }
  return pickedRows;
}

//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------//
function getRandomInt(min, max) {
  min = Math.ceil(min);
  max = Math.floor(max);
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min)) + min;
}

//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------//

function enemyTeam() {

// How many enemies?  
  var count = getRandomInt(1,5);
// Enemy Database - each enemy should follow the below layout.
// Player level required to encounter || Name || Level || Race || Class || HP || Max HP || Damage || Def || Initiative || Max Initiative || Damage callout
  var fromValues = [

  ['1','Goblin Thug','1','Goblin','Tank','6','6','1','2','1','1','Blurgh!'],
  ['1','Goblin Snot','1','Goblin','DPS','4','4','2','1','1','1','Oww!'],
  ['1','Goblin Stitcher','1','Goblin','Healer','2','2','1','2','1','1','Gahh!']

  ]

// Define enemy list
  var enemylist = selectRandomElements(fromValues, count);
  Logger.log(enemylist);
  enemylist.forEach(function(array){
  array.splice(0,1);
 }); 
  Logger.log(enemylist);
  var ssBS = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Battle Stats');
  var enemyrange = ssBS.getRange(7,1,count,11);

// Place in Battle Stats tab
  enemyrange.setValues(enemylist);
}
```

As I say, this works for the most part and returns 1-4 random enemies from the list, but every now and then it removes the wrong element, or even removes two, and throws a 'The number of columns in the data does not match the number of columns in the range. The data has 9 but the range has 11.' error. For example, just now I ran it and it worked twice, then I got the error...

First log shows:

> [19-10-12 18:38:35:711 BST] [[1, Goblin Thug, 1, Goblin, Tank, 6, 6, 1, 2, 1, >1, Blurgh!], [1, Goblin Thug, 1, Goblin, Tank, 6, 6, 1, 2, 1, 1, Blurgh!], [1, >Goblin Stitcher, 1, Goblin, Healer, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, Gahh!]]

Second log shows:

> [19-10-12 18:38:35:711 BST] [[1, Goblin, Tank, 6, 6, 1, 2, 1, 1, Blurgh!], [1, >Goblin, Tank, 6, 6, 1, 2, 1, 1, Blurgh!], [Goblin Stitcher, 1, Goblin, Healer, >2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, Gahh!]]

What I'd want to see:

> [19-10-12 18:38:35:711 BST] [[Goblin Thug, 1, Goblin, Tank, 6, 6, 1, 2, 1, >1, Blurgh!], [Goblin Thug, 1, Goblin, Tank, 6, 6, 1, 2, 1, 1, Blurgh!], [Goblin Stitcher, 1, Goblin, Healer, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, Gahh!]]

Any help appreciated.

**EDIT:** Took a break and think I figured out why it's happening sporadically. It only seems to happen when the same row is picked multiple times - I assume because it's splicing the same row twice. Just need to know how to stop that.

Comment: The error being thrown shows that the issue is not with the code you shared but with the selectRandomElements function. My guess is that you are using incorrect range coordinates to get the values for your array from the spreadsheet. Could you please share the code for the 1st function?

Comment: @AntonDementiev - Sure thing. Edited! Thanks.

Comment: Which line of code produces the error? The error clearly happens when you are trying to either 1) write to the sheet by calling setValues()  or 2) get data from the sheet by calling getRange(). I don't see any calls to either function in the code you shared. There are no 'columns' in JS arrays

Comment: 1.Show stringified arrays: `Logger.log({'firstLog': JSON.stringify(enemylist)})` 2. Provide  complete code (start to end) or preferably [mcve]. 3. `slice()` doesn't change the initial array

Comment: Something else must be between first log and second log that you're not showing.

Comment: @AntonDementiev - Edited to include call. It's enemyrange.setValues(enemylist); that throws the error. The array sometimes end up the wrong size.

Comment: @TheMaster - no, there's nothing in between, mate - I copied it directly as it is.

Comment: Took a break and think I figured out why it's happening sporadically. It only seems to happen when the same row is picked multiple times - I assume because it's splicing the same row twice.

Comment: Add it as a answer below

Comment: @TheMaster But it's not an answer. I still don't know how to fix it. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`slice()` makes a shallow copy. Try

```
var pickedRow = fromValueRows[pickedIndex].slice(0);
```

to make a copy of the inner array too.

Comment: Hey, buddy. Thanks for helping, firstly! Second, changing to that throws a new error - "The number of columns in the data does not match the number of columns in the range. The data has 0 but the range has 11. (line 90, file "Battle Handling")" Line 90 is the same as before - enemyrange.setValues(enemylist); The splice further down seems to be completely emptying the array now.

Comment: That seems to have done it. Tested it 20 times and no errors so far. Thanks so much for the help, mate. Answer accepted! (also tried to up-vote, but <15 rep.)

Comment: @Lee Try to understand why it worked. Learn about differences between deep and shallow copy, and Array.slice()

Comment: Will do, mate. Thanks again for the help! :)